# How to get rid of '\n' as a part of dict value when assigning from text file

Tags: python, dictionary

I write function to change JSON with provided informations, specifically EAN, which I read from file. EAN is put with \n at the end and I'm not able to get rid of it.

I tried replace('\n', ''), value[:-3] but that does affect only number.
I tried add parameter newline=""/None in open function, only adding \r between number and \n

*eans.txt is simply file containing eans each on new line without any gaps or tabs*
    material_template = 
    {
        "eanUpc": "",
    }

```
def get_ean():
    with open('eans.txt', 'r') as x:
        first = x.readline()
        all = x.read()
    with open('eans.txt', 'w') as y:
        y.writelines(all[1:])
    return first

def make_material(material_template):
    material_template["eanUpc"] = get_ean()

    print(material_template) 
    print(material_template["eanUpc"])

make_material(material_template)
```

> > > {'eanUpc': '061500127178\n'}
> > >
> > > 061500127178

thanks in advance

Comment: Use the `trim()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `return first` use `return first.strip("\n")` to trim off the `\n`.

However, I question the organization of the original system... reading one line then writing the whole file back over the original.

- What if the process fails during the processing of one line?  The data is lost
- IF this file is large, you'll be doing a lot of disk i/o

Maybe read one line at a time, and save an offset into the file (last_processed) into another file?  Then you can seek to that location.

Answer (score 0):

Should use `return first.strip()`. It is removing leading white-spaces.